# Previously revealed manager key for contract

Tags: transactions, operation, delegating

What this error `Previously revealed manager key for contract <address>` means?

I tried to craft a delegation tx from a not-revealed address. Putting a reveal and a delegate operation in the same tx. Can I do this?

Any hint?
Here's the tx:

```
  "operations": {
    "branch": "BLWsiu1byZCyh6pMKUcHUhxYdLNNj1CLiUNkaKBASGeyVE2rEzz",
    "contents": [
      {
        "kind": "reveal",
        "counter": "6555522",
        "fee": "0",
        "gas_limit": "15400",
        "storage_limit": "0",
        "public_key": "edpkvDP9Q3ZzddbHUXctMWuo7mgEugiZyPzELF2kGdrJsnM4Bid92W",
        "source": "tz1bVFjNz8vGseuBCdT565qvZgiu6fKwXVCL"
      },
      {
        "kind": "delegation",
        "counter": "6555523",
        "fee": "1420",
        "gas_limit": "15400",
        "storage_limit": "300",
        "source": "tz1bVFjNz8vGseuBCdT565qvZgiu6fKwXVCL",
        "delegate": "tz1aRoaRhSpRYvFdyvgWLL6TGyRoGF51wDjM"
      }
    ],
    "protocol": "PsCARTHAGazKbHtnKfLzQg3kms52kSRpgnDY982a9oYsSXRLQEb",
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the following things happened: 1) you sent reveal+delegation first time and it was accepted by the node, but stuck in the mempool (due to too low fee for such gas limit, I guess). 2) you tried to send it again, but since the first pair of reveal+delegation already was in the mempool, node said that you already revealed the pub key. This is just my guess...

Comment: Agree with Groxan here. The root problem here must be that the fee is too low. 1420 is simply too low (for bakers with standard configuration) and if the fee is set to 0 in the reveal, the delegation fee must also cover for the reveal.